# filtering with attributes in xml

Tags: flash-builder

my xml name is  dp in flashbuilder 4.5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<POWER_OK>
    <yes id="1" name="POWER SEATED">
        <yes id="11" name="IS 110 VOLT"></yes>
        <no id="12" name="CHANGE IT"></no>
    </yes>
    <no id="2" name="DATA IN SCREEN">
        <yes id="21" name="RETRY BOOT"></yes>
        <no id="22" name="VIDEO FALURE"></no>
    </no>
```

i'm trying to filter this data with
dp.yes.(@id = "11")
not working pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dp.yes.(@id == "11");
```

(note double equals sign)